# How to make this simple SQL query into a Linq Statement?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have the following SQL statement which is going through a table and selecting out a group of results based on the the data definition. From that group, I get the single result with the highest revision for that group. Now the SQL has been easy, but translating this into Linq so far has yielded nothing which I can use. Can anyone help with this?

```
select * from datasheet ds where ds.revisionnum = 
(select max(revisionnum) from datasheet where datadefinitionid = 34) 
       and ds.isparent = 1  -- is parent will be true for this query
```

This is about as far as I get with the Linq Statement before I stumbled:

```
var query = from ds in context.DataSheets 
             where ds.IsParent == true 
             && ds.RevisionNum  --- ?????
```

Thanks in advance!

**Code Update**

After fumbling around for a while, this is what we came up with:

```
var dataSheet = _dataSheetRepository.All.Where(
                            d => d.DataDefinitionID == i.ID &&
                            d.IsParent == true);

var currentDataSheet = (from ds in dataSheet
                        where (ds.RevisionNum == (from s in dataSheet select
                        s.RevisionNum).Max()) select ds).SingleOrDefault();
```

Using two variables gave us the ability to narrow down which sheet collection we were looking for, and then using the linq query on the second var, we were able to narrow down which actual revision number of that collection we wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try something like that

```
var query = from ds in context.DataSheets 
             where ds.IsParent == true 
             && ds.RevisionNum == context.DataSheets.Where(
                                  ds => ds.DataDefinitionId == 34).Max(
                                  ds => ds.RevisionNum)
```

subquery could be converted into linq expression as well

Comment: Argh... my eyes hurt every time I see a boolean checked against `true` or `false`...

Comment: Actually sometimes it makes code more readable. However in this case I agree, it seems to be redundant.

Comment: It's a personal preference I suppose, but typically it tells me that the person who wrote the code doesn't really understand boolean expressions.

Comment: For the same reason bool values are true and false.  It reads better, and thus is easier/faster to understand.

Comment: As much as I'd like to say that this code will work, it's really not doing much for me. Where I'd be expecting one item returned, I'm still getting many items.

Comment: @Andrei, your code got me close, but it too some time to tinker with it before getting exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Chris, could you please show what did you come up with? Just curious.

Comment: @Anderi, check the question up top. I added the code that we used as our solution.

Answer (score 0):

May I recommend the tool http://www.linqpad.net/

It is great for creating and testing linq expressions against sql and Odata web services.